# JS embedded on other sites - how can I use jQuery without screwing up other jQuery installations?

Tags: javascript, jquery, conflicting-libraries

I'm working on some JavaScript that will be embedded on other websites (think like Google Analytics or AdSense). There is some hardcore JS being done -- AJAX requests, animations, JSON(P).

I've written the prototype using jQuery, and really want to keep using it, but this might cause a problem when embedded on the other sites if they also have jQuery installed -- probably even a different version.

Is there a nice way around this? The best solution I've got so far is to simply replace all occurrences of `jQuery` with `kQuery`, and `$` with `$kQuery`, so there is no naming conflict. Any suggestions? How can I be as compatible as possible with their existing JavaScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `noConflict` mode for jQuery; that's what you need. jQuery saves the original values of `window.jQuery` and `window.$` as a local copy before it overwrites them.

So, a solution is:

```
var kQuery = $kQuery = $.noConflict( true );
```

Which replaces `window.jQuery` and `window.$` with the original values and returns a reference to jQuery itself

---

And if you don't want to change your code at all, just wrap it in:

```
(function( $ ){
   // Your code with $
})( $.noConflict( true ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 this might cause a problem when embedded on the other sites if they also have jQuery installed -- probably even a different version
```

I don't think this is true. I've had no problems switching between at least 3 different versions of jQuery, it is  [backwards compatible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281438/how-good-is-jquerys-backward-compatibility)

Comment: I might be using new features (e.g. JSONP support) that aren't available in previous versions.