# Is jQuery BBQ-Plugin still working with JQuery 1.7x?

Tags: jquery, compatibility, jquery-bbq, jquery-1.7

Short question, but couldn't find a hint to that anywhere: it seems that the [jQuery BBQ](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/) Plugin is only tested to work with jQuery until v1.4.2. Now the current version of jQuery is v1.7.1 and i wonder if the Plugin will be still working?

Haven't used it before and just want to avoid wasting time hopelessly in getting it working...

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old thread, but just in case anyone comes across it like I have - I'm using jQuery 1.9.1 and just by including the jQuery BBQ plugin I get a JavaScript error:

```
TypeError: f is undefined
```

So it looks like it has been broken with this version of jQuery (or even a previous one). I'm off to search for a new jQuery history plugin...

Comment: If you download the unminimized version of BBQ, you'll see the error is related to '$.browser' returning null.  This is because this function has been removed in jQuery 1.9.  You can reintroduce this functionality using jQuery.migrate - http://blog.jquery.com/2013/05/08/jquery-migrate-1-2-1-released/

Comment: That's really good to know, thanks - I didn't know about the migrate functionality. (I have actually moved on to using [History.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/) though, although good to know about that)

Answer (score 2):

jQuery is good with backward compatibility, something which works with jQuery 1.4.2 will definetily work for jQuery 1.7.1 For more [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281438/how-good-is-jquerys-backward-compatibility). Also you can read [release notes](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/11/21/jquery-1-7-1-released/) for jQuery 1.7.1

Comment: I think it depends. For instance, the change made to .attr() could easily break a plugin, right?.