# Back button not changing hash at first time

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, browser-history, jquery-bbq

My question is like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10822544/back-button-not-updating-hash-in-iframe-on-ie), but my problem is not in IE (not tested), but in Chrome and Firefox. Anyway, that question has no responses.

I'm using [BBQ plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/), with this code:

```
  $(window).bind('hashchange', function(e) {

            var href = $.param.fragment();

            hrefOld = $("#loadZone").attr("src");
            centerZoneActivePage = href;

            // Create container for this url's content and store a reference to it in
            // the cache.
            cache[ href ] = $("#loadZone").attr("src", href);
            alert("new: " +href);
   });

   // Since the event is only triggered when the hash changes, we need to trigger
   // the event now, to handle the hash the page may have loaded with.
   $(window).trigger( 'hashchange' );
```

What is happening, is that when I'm loading new pages in an iframe ("#loadZone"), the hash is changing correctly. But when I click in browser back button, the previous page is loading, but is not changing hash. When clicked by second time, hash changes and active page maintains in iframe. I don't understand why hash is not changing at first time, as previous page loading.

Note: the alert message only appears at second time in back button clicks.

Summary of back button clicks:

- First click: Iframe previous page loaded, alert message not displayed, hash not changed;
- Second click: Iframe page is still the same, alert message is displayed, hash is changed.

How to synchronize this?
I'm using jquery-1.7.1.js. Anyone has used BBQ plugin with this version, with success? I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8680933/is-jquery-bbq-plugin-still-working-with-jquery-1-7x?rq=1), but its not conclusive.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I solved the problem, deleting the iframe and creating a new one for each time a page load is required. Not pretty, but solved. Somehow, the iframe was in conflict with history control.