# Are newer jquery versions backwards compatible with earlier versions?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, backwards-compatibility

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How good is jQuery’s backward-compatibility?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281438/how-good-is-jquerys-backward-compatibility)

I'm adding some new features to my site which require newer jquery and jquery ui versions. I have a lot of older code which was written for an earlier jquery/ui version, and I'm wondering if it's safe to just load the newer versions.

Comment: what is your current jquery version? You are seeking backward compactbility with what version?

Comment: It depends entirely on what methods you're using from which versions of jQuery. Check out the information [about **deprecated** methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/). This is, incidentally, an entirely un-answerable question without seeing the whole of your jQuery code, and knowing which version you're moving *from* and which you're moving *to*. Voting to close as 'not constructive.'

Comment: The SHOULD be, but it depends how old you're talking and what functionality is being used. I recently updated a site from 1.52 to 1.81 without any issues, but YMMV.

Comment: I had lots of troubles when moving from 1.7 to 1.8, including stuff related to dimensions (include or not borders, margins, etc.) and jqueryUI which was not compatible with 1.8 ... They might have been fixed by now though...

Comment: Just be aware that jquery ui 1.8 serie is quite buggy mostly due to curCSS been removed from jquery 1.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to bug fixes and improvements there can't be a compatibility by 100%.