# JQuery file version conflicts

Tags: jquery

I am using JQuery extensively in my project. Initially used for inline editing in razor webgrid for hiding and showing textboxes after edit, update etc. For that to work I refer jquery files jquery-1.8.3.js. After that I implemented JQuery dialog for showing the message. For that I refer another version of JQuery. But now the problem is lot of JQuery files are there in my project which slows the loading of page as well as if one functioanlity works another one will not work, because of the version differences. Please anyone help on the below queries.

1. Where can I find the latest JQuery files ?
2. Is all the functionalities in older version works with the new version ?
3. How I will know one of the functionalities in older version works in the new ?
4. In MVC, in order to reduce the loading time, how I can refer the JQuery files ?

Answer (score 1):

1. http://jquery.com/download/
2. Yes, most of them should.
3. Test for the functionalities that you use, rather than testing for all.
4. Just load one version and not multiple, and use minified version.

Also check [How good is jQuery's support for backwards compatibility?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281438/how-good-is-jquerys-backward-compatibility)

Comment: Thanks Hanky. I refer the latest JQuery files. But still the problem persists. I mean I am using JQuery dialog to confirm deletion of a client and once the client is deleted I needs to remove that client from grid using another version of JQuery, but that is not working. I refer the latest JQuery files

Answer (score 0):

Try it--

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var $jq = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```