# What are jQuery's Backwards Compatibility Guarantees

Tags: javascript, jquery, backwards-compatibility

Does jQuery make any version-to-version compatibility guarantees?  For example following [semantic versioning](http://semver.org/) or do you just have to read the release notes every time?

Note: I have seen [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281438/how-good-is-jquerys-backward-compatibility) that ask how good compatibility has actually been.  This question is strictly about the promises made by the project.

Comment: Your question is answered with this answer on the linked question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20466738/16587

Comment: Can you please quote it?  The answer you linked talks only about upgrading to 1.9.  This question is about future compatibility in general.

Comment: "Future compatibility in General is a "in flux" sort of thing and best asked to the author's of JQuery. If the past teaches us anything, it's that things change and present compatibility is no guarantee of future compatibility.

Comment: A quality project will have promises of future compatibility.  These are generally things like "we will change the major version number when we break compatibility".  I agree that this is best posed to the jQuery devs however I was wondering if anyone knew.  I guess I will ask them and post the result here.  However this question is still not a duplicate and I request reopening it so that the proper answer can be posted here.

Comment: Whether "Off topic" because this is a question for JQuery devs or a duplicate because it was answered already (again, see the linked answer, and even the accepted answer), this sort of question really doesn't belong here.  Not every question tangentially related to programming has a place on Stack Overflow, and that's ok.

Comment: You have to read the release notes from time to time. With Microsoft dropping support for XP next month, i'd expect jquery to drop support for IE8 in a version or two (meaning they'll just stop upgrading the 1.x version)