Update jQuery from version 3.5.1 to version 3.7.1
I'm updating the jQuery library on my website from version 3.5.1 to version 3.7.1. I need to address all the functions that have been removed to avoid problems. Does anyone know which functions were removed during these updates?
I tried to search out on the release notes but I didn't find anything.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281438/how-well-does-jquery-support-backward-compatibility

jQuery team are generally good with keeping to semver where minor releases (.5 -> .7) don't make breaking changes.

https://blog.jquery.com/2023/05/11/jquery-3-7-0-released-staying-in-order/ "We do not expect compatibility issues when upgrading from a jQuery 3.0+ version"

It would be best if you only had to worry about the removal of deprecated APIs when migrating to jQuery 4.x

See: "jQuery 4.0.0 BETA!" ~ jQuery Blog


jQuery 4.x
These were removed in 4.x:

Functions:

jQuery.cssNumber
jQuery.cssProps
jQuery.isArray
jQuery.parseJSON
jQuery.nodeName
jQuery.isFunction
jQuery.isWindow
jQuery.camelCase
jQuery.type
jQuery.now
jQuery.isNumeric
jQuery.trim
jQuery.fx.interval


Prototype:

push
sort
splice


Events:

focusin
focosout




OP is migrating from 3.5.1 to version 3.7.1.  not 4.x

@Death-is-the-real-truth I know that. This was for a future user who would see this post x-years from now.

for that you can pst your own question along with answer. So provide you that facility

You can use this compare function on GitHub:
Comparing changes from 3.5.1 to 3.7.1
Or you can read about every release at:
Releases: jQuery
